# Can't get active link to work with React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was hoping using the NavLink component in react router v4 would be pretty simple, but maybe my components are wired the way they should be. Anyways, I have my NavBar in it's own component, and nothing is really happening on clicking the NavBar ...

```
<nav style={styles.sidebar}>
  <div style={styles.logoWrapper}>
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <ul style={styles.ulList}>
    <NavLink style={styles.sidebarItem} activeStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', color: '#313c59'}} to="/app/editor/basicInfo">
      <FontAwesome
        size='3x'
        border={false}
        name="wrench"
        style={{marginBottom: 10}}
      />
      Editor
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink style={styles.sidebarItem} activeStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', color: '#313c59'}} to="/app/utilities">
      <FontAwesome
        size='3x'
        border={false}
        name="anchor"
        style={{marginBottom: 10}}
      />
      Utilities
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink style={styles.sidebarItem} activeStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', color: '#313c59'}} to="/app/settings">
      <FontAwesome
        size='3x'
        border={false}
        name="cog"
        style={{marginBottom: 10}}
      />
      Settings
    </NavLink>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But I don't know if this is where the weirdness comes in, and would be interested if anyone else has better design patterns for this ... but a lot of my app may or may not have a navbar, or it might be completely different, and so I created a component that figures out which bar to render right now ...

```
//inside componentDidUpdate()
const path = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

if (path === "app") {
  this.setState({onLandingPage: false})
}

if (path != "app") {
  this.setState({onLandingPage: true})
}

//inside render func
<div>
  { (this.state.onLandingPage) ? <NavBar /> : <EditorNavBar /> }
</div>
```

It's pretty simple, it's just checking the first pathname, and then rendering as such. That parts working, but is it messing up the props coming down somehow. Any wisdom or thoughts would be great!

**UPDATE:**

Also here is how I'm wrapping up the component at the bottom ... it's the fist time using Radium, so there is a lot of wrapping going on:

```
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default withRouter(connector(Radium(EditorNavBar)));
```

Comment: do you get any error on console?

Comment: @ReiDien no, I don't. I did at first, with displaying a value in a text area without using the value prop and defaultValue prop, and I was hoping that would help the issue. It didn't :/

Comment: @ReiDien I will say, I keep trying to log out anything going on in the nav component and I can't get anything to hit. I just don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NavBar isn't being updated due to [Update Blocking](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking). Try wrapping the NavBar with `withRouter`. This will re-render the component when location changes.

P.S. A cleaner approach to choosing the correct NavBar is with Routes (and this negates the need for `withRouter` as the component will re-render on path change like any other route):

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/app" component={EditorNavBar}/>
  <Route component={NavBar}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks so much for that info. I'm like 90% sure I did wrap the NavBar with withRouter, but I'll double check tomorrow. But you're right that is way cleaner. I'll work on implementing that as well. Will let you know if I did forget to wrap it with withRouter.

Comment: @TaylorKing also, if you do choose to use routes to render your navbar, this will negate the need for withRouter, as it'll naturally re-render on path change.

Comment: I did confirm that it is wrapped with withConnector, but I'm also using Radium for the first time, so wrapping up the component has been a little tricky ... i'll update my post so you can see that if interested. But one more question to the cleaner approach. I tend to overthink, but on the "/" I want the Home component to also load ... can I also do component={Home} and also add in the route config sideBarComponent={NavBar} ? Thoughts on that?

Comment: @TaylorKing You're thinking in React-Router 3 mode. I did that for a while too but RR4 is much simpler. Decouple your sidebar from your content components. In your sidebar file, place the switch statement I put in my answer. In your content/main/page (whatever you're calling it), put another switch component with what you'd like to be displayed there. In other words: no "sideBarComponent" property required (or allowed for that matter). Here's an example from the docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar

Comment: Thanks for your help! I believe I'm starting to get the grasp of it ... I refactored it down to your suggestion, which is definitely a lot cleaner, and there are still a few kinks I'm working, but for the most part it's working as expected.

Comment: That's great. Glad I could help.

Comment: After wasted around 90 minutes, here's the accurate solution.